# Sending a message to all actors within an ActorSystem

Tags: scala, akka

Is it possible to send a message to *all* actors in an actor system? I've been looking at the [Broadcast router](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/routing.html#broadcast-messages-scala) example, but that is so marginal I can't comprehend how I add actors to the router dynamically.

We are using scala for akka.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
system.actorSelection("/user/*") ! msg
```

Selects all children of the guardian and sends them the msg.

Comment: The question was about sending to all actors, though, not just just children of the root.  What about grandchildren(/...) of the root?

Answer (score 9):

If you want send a message to all actor who are dynamically created, you can use [eventBus](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1-M2/scala/event-bus.html)

I personally use the system.eventStream for my case.

From an actor, you can send to everyone :

```
context.system.eventStream.publish(StatisticsMessage())
```

or directly with system.

actor must subscribe with :

```
context.system.eventStream.subscribe
```

I extends from :

```
trait SubscriberActor extends Actor {

  def subscribedClasses: Seq[Class[_]]

  override def preStart() {
    super.preStart()
    subscribedClasses.foreach(this.context.system.eventStream.subscribe(this.self, _))
  }

  override def postStop() {
    subscribedClasses.foreach(this.context.system.eventStream.unsubscribe(this.self, _))
    super.postStop()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks twillouer! I've been thinking about that as well, but I really miss good examples for that.

Comment: 1. Probably in `postStop` you need "unsubscribe"; 2. it might be a better idea to unsubscribe _before_ calling `super.postStop()`.